# Почему в переменная начинает хранить значение infinity?

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу понять почему переменная let sQuare, становиться infiity.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


let random = Math.random()*10;
let nTrials = 5000; // кол-во испытаний   
let nSteps = 500; // кол-во шагов
let arrN = [];
let sTwo = []; // список квадратов отклонения

// подсчет в цикле
for (let i = 10; i < nSteps; i+=10)
{
    arrN.push(i); 
    s = 0;
    sQuare = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j <= nTrials; j++)
    {
        s += s + getRandomInt(-1,1);
        sQuare += Math.sqrt(s);
    }
    console.log(sQuare);
    sQuare = sQuare/nTrials;
    sTwo.push(sQuare)
}
console.log(sTwo);
```

Comment: Потому что переменная `s` через 1024 шага принимает значение 141678148278842379004822862942563989632297700598140919236650821104078439698416103543490594735316089910293438176112574479271862232370453445928723548297971478778240260974012133049234337994738277870707615938305908222599673843423777727001899018980124499512174267863669563040790780484428119384036900967228867870720 и после этого улетает в бесконечность из-за ограниченной точности вычислений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну `NaN` оно становится, потому что

```
s += s + getRandomInt(-1,1); // изначально s = 0 и может стать s < 0
sQuare += Math.sqrt(s);
```

приводит к тому, что вычисляется квадратный корень из отрицательного числа

А `Infinity` вылезает, потому что 5000 раз вы делаете

```
s += s + getRandomInt(-1,1);
```

Что приводит к уходу из диапазона

например, s += s выполненное 5000 раз - равно s0 * 2^5000 - s0 * 1e1505, что как-то многовато :)

Comment: При чем здесь "int диапазон"?

Comment: @Igor - подправил, у уходу из диапазона чисел как таковых

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let j = 0; j <= nTrials; j++)
{
    let r = getRandomInt(-1,1);
    sQuare += r * r;
}
```